# Is anyone using glassbox framework for automated troubleshooting and monitoring of Java EE apps?

Tags: java, testing, instrumentation

[Glassbox](http://glassbox.sourceforge.net/glassbox/Project.html) seems to be very promising but wondering if anyone is using it? Also are there any other alternatives to it?

Comment: This is quite relevant to Java-programmers.  If you are not a Java programmer then do not vote to close it.